# Accessing an array of pointer to strings

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Looking for some clarification on a specific topic related to addressing an array of strings.  There seem to be several related issues but I wasn't able to find one that discussed my question.  If this has been asked before please point me to the relevant thread.

In the snippet of code below (check printf statement), I use the same variable to access the value at a memory location and the address of the memory location.  I'm not quite sure if this is how I'm supposed to write this piece of code.  Is there a better way that will clearly indicate if I'm accessing the address or the value?

```
char *board[NUM_MAX_ROWS] = {"0101001",
                             "1101011"};

int main()
{
    int i, num_rows=0, num_cols=0;

    num_cols = strlen(board[0]);
    num_rows = ARR_SIZE(board);

    for (i=0; i<num_rows; i++)
        printf("%s stored at %p\n", board[i], board[i]);

}
```

My first attempt looked like this

```
while(*board != '\0')
{
    printf("%s stored ar %p\n", *board, board);
    board++;
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work :) but I'm still not quite sure about how this is interpreted by the compiler.

Thanks.

Comment: Your first piece of code is correct. You're passing a pointer (`char*`) twice - interpretation of argument then depends on format specifiers. `%s` will print chars starting at adress and stopping at NUL character. `%p` will simply print the adress.

Comment: Could you explain why the second OBVIOUSLY does not work?

Comment: The second piece failed to compile with error: lvalue required as increment operand (in reference to board++). I thought it would increment a pointer.

Comment: When you say `board++`, array is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. That yields an r-value which you're not allowed to increment.

Comment: additionally, assuming u switch out board with a temp pointer as shinkou does, it still wont be '\0' since that pointer points to the string itself and not individual characters,

Answer (score 1):

You can get the first attempt to work by dereferencing the pointer once to get address  of the string itself.

`printf("%s stored ar %p\n", *board, *board);`

Btw when you write using array syntax, it is actually identical to

`printf("%s stored ar %p\n", *(board+i), *(board+i));`

Edit: i seem to have miss read the question.. fixing.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *board[] = {"0101001",
                 "1101011",
                 0}; /* note this final 0 as a terminator for stopping the loop */

int main()
{
    int i, num_rows=0, num_cols=0;
    char **c;

    c = &board[0];
    while(*c)
    {
        printf("%s stored ar %p\n", *c, *c);
        c++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, you'll have to have a loop stopper if you do so.  Also, there are people who advocate using `NULL` instead of `0` for clarity.